# How to maximize the sum of consecutive booleans?

Tags: python, or-tools

I am working to create a program enabling teachers to allocate exam sessions to students using *or-tools*.

In order to have the desired behavior I need to be able to maximize the number of consecutive slots that are active in order to have no gaps between the slots.

For example, if I have the slots [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] I want to reward a solution like [3, 4, 5] instead of [0, 2, 5].

The big problem is that I don't really know how to do that, I had the idea to maximize an objective function that would summarize for each slot the preceding and following slots' values.
I would also want the slots to not be at the start of the session.
This is important because not all the sessions have the same number of slots and we want all the sessions to finish at the same time.

Something like this:

```
for session in possibilities:
  for slot in range(len(session)):
    if slot == 5:
      sum(session[slot] + session[slot-1])
    elif slot != 0:
      sum(session[slot-1] + session[slot] + session[slot+1])
```

But I don't know if there is a better way to do it.

Below is the structure in which I store the different BoolVars:

```
timeslot_possibilities = [[{} for _ in range(max_size_slot)] for _ in all_sessions]

for session in timeslot_possibilities:
  for i in range(max_size_slot):
    for student in all_students:
      session[i][(teacher_students[student], student)] = model.NewBoolVar(
                    f"{[teacher.name for teacher in teacher_students[student]]}_st{student}"
                    f"_session{timeslot_possibilities.index(session)}_slot{i}"
                )
```

1. `max_size_slot` is the maximum number of slot permitted by session
2. `teacher_students` is a **dict** giving the teachers linked to a student

If anyone has another idea I am all ears.

Comment: This sounds like a very interesting problem. So you have free slots and want to maximize choosing sets of consecutive slots? And if there's a tie we always choose the slots with higher value?

Comment: That is it, the only difference in your description is that we prefer sets of consecutive slots that includes or finishes with the last available slot. Here in the example it would be 5 that must be included.

Comment: You could penalize the number of slots that are not active but at least one previous and next are active. BTW you could try to ask this question over at https://or.stackexchange.com/ they can probably give you a better formulation

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion to you:

Your issue sounds like a choice problem. I'd generate all the possible choices then rank them with a function that follows your preferences.

Here's how I do it:

```
from itertools import combinations
from numpy import std

def get_best_choice(choices):
  best_choices = []
  best_score = min([std(choice) for choice in choices])
  for choice in choices:
    if std(choice) == best_score:
      best_choices.append(choice)
  return best_choices[-1]  # We return the last element from best choices

number_of_slots_needed = 3  # Could be anything between 1-5
free_slots = [1,2,4,5]  # I'm assuming this is sorted, if not just sort it here

choices = list(combinations(free_slots, number_of_slots_needed))

final_choice = get_best_choice(choices)
```

By doing so I get the result:

```
>>> final_choice
(2, 4, 5)
```

I am using STD function as our grading function since it will reward our values being closer together, and give us lower scores for closer packs.

Then I use `min()` to get the tied best score's choices. And I choose the last one out of those, so that it has slot 5, if slot 5 is available and part of the optimal solution. (This depends on having an ordered list for `free_slots`)

What do you think?

Comment: This seems like a good idea, thanks. I will try to implement a function that will select the good choices. If I encounter another issue in doing so I'll let you know.